# System.FormatException Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: c#

Есть код, в ComboBoxPrecision выбираю значение (0.01) и при конвертации в Double вылазит ошибка. В чем проблема? (Ошибка вылазит на 4й строчке)

```
InOrders = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxOrders.Text);
ServiceOrders = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxOrderService.Text);
NumOfChannels = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxChannels.Text);
Precision = Convert.ToDouble(comboBoxPrecision.SelectedItem.ToString());
richTextBox1.Text = "";
```

Comment: `comboBoxPrecision.SelectedItem.ToString()` - ?

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в десятичном разделителе - точке.

```
Precision = Convert.ToDouble(comboBoxPrecision.SelectedItem.ToString(),
  NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Comment: Святой Вы человек, а я 3 года мучаюсь с `Replace(‘.’, ‘,’)` хД

Comment: На сколько помнится, подобные преобразователи берут настройки десятичного разделителя из настроек системы. Поэтому у нас в России по умолчанию разделитель - запятая, а не точка.

Comment: @ГеннадийП настройки берутся из `Thread.CultureInfo` текущего потока. А уже это по умолчанию определяется настройками системы.