# Программа перестает работать после начала вычислений

Tags: c#

Написал программу, после нажатия кнопки Пуск, программа просто виснет и все. Ошибок никаких не вылазит. Помогите устранить проблему. Думаю причина кроется в этой строчке `Precision = Convert.ToDouble(comboBoxPrecision.SelectedItem.ToString(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);` В ней конвертируется значение 0.01 в Double

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class WorkForm : Form
    {
        private int InOrders;
        private int ServiceOrders;
        private int NumOfChannels;
        private double Precision = 0;
        private double OrderInterval;
        private double ChannelInterval;
        private int TotalTime;
        private double CmoTime;
        private ulong NumOfOrders = 0;
        private ulong ServedOrders;
        private int CmoPosition;
        private int[] ChannelBusy;
        private double[] ServiceTimeOfChannel;
        private Random rand = new Random();

        // функция которая преобразовывает точность для дальнейшего использования в программе и функциях
        private int Precition(double e)
        {
            int Tochnost = 0;

            if (e == 0.1)
                Tochnost = 10;

            if (e == 0.01)
                Tochnost = 100;

            if (e == 0.001)
                Tochnost = 1000;

            return Tochnost;
        }

        // Число знаков для округления исходя из точности
        private int ChisloZnakov(double Prec)
        {
            int a = 0;

            if (Prec == 0.1)
                a = 1;
            if (Prec == 0.01)
                a = 2;
            if (Prec == 0.001)
                a = 3;
            return a;
        }
        // функция которая возвращает интервал времени между заявками, либо интер. времени обслуж. канала
        private double OrdersInterval(int NumOfOrders, double Tochnost)
        {
            int CelayaChast;
            double Ostatok;

            CelayaChast = Precition(Tochnost) / NumOfOrders;
            Ostatok = (Precition(Tochnost) / (double)NumOfOrders - CelayaChast) * 10;

            if (Ostatok >= 5)
                CelayaChast++;

            return (double)(CelayaChast / (double)Precition(Tochnost));
        }

        // генератор моментов времени
        private double TimeGenerator(bool FirstOrder, double Interval, double Tochnost)
        {
            double NewTime;
            int GenerationInterval = (int)(Interval * Precition(Tochnost) + 1);

            // только если это не первая заявка
            if (!FirstOrder)
            {
                // исключение генерации нуля => повторяющееся время
                do
                {
                    NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);
                } while (NewTime == 0);
            }
            else
                NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);

            return Math.Round(NewTime, ChisloZnakov(Tochnost));
        }

        // проверяет наличие новой заявки
        private bool NewOrder(double TimeOfCmo, double IntervalOfOrder, ulong NumberOfOrders)
        {
            if (TimeOfCmo >= IntervalOfOrder * (NumberOfOrders))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
        // проверка системы в текущий момент времени
        private void CmoCheck(int TotalTime, double CmoTime, int NumOfChannels)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (CmoPosition != 0)
            {
                while (i < NumOfChannels)
                {
                    if (ChannelBusy[i] == 1)
                    {
                        if (((ServiceTimeOfChannel[i] <= CmoTime) && (CmoTime <= TotalTime)) || ((CmoTime > TotalTime) && (ServiceTimeOfChannel[i] <= TotalTime)))
                        {
                            ChannelBusy[i] = 0;
                            ServiceTimeOfChannel[i] = 0;
                            CmoPosition--;
                            richTextBox1.Text += (i + 1).ToString() + "-й канал обслужил заявку" + "\n";
                            ServedOrders++;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        // запись заявок в каналы и генерация времени обслуживания в канале + окончание обслуживания
        private void CmoWork(double CmoTime, int NumOfChannels, double ChannelInterval, double e)
        {
            double ChannelWorkTime;
            int i = 0;
            // если система свободна, то запись осуществляется в первый канал
            if (CmoPosition == 0)
            {
                ChannelBusy[0] = 1;
                ChannelWorkTime = TimeGenerator(false, ChannelInterval, e);
                ServiceTimeOfChannel[0] = CmoTime + ChannelWorkTime;
                CmoPosition++;
                InfoOrder(CmoTime, 0, ChannelWorkTime);
            }
            else // иначе, идет запись в первый свободный канал
            {
                if (CmoPosition != NumOfChannels)
                {
                    while (i < NumOfChannels)
                    {
                        if (ChannelBusy[i] == 0)
                        {
                            ChannelBusy[i] = 1;
                            ChannelWorkTime = TimeGenerator(false, ChannelInterval, e);
                            ServiceTimeOfChannel[i] = CmoTime + ChannelWorkTime;
                            CmoPosition++;
                            InfoOrder(CmoTime, i, ChannelWorkTime);
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Заявка не может быть принята на обслуживание - КАНАЛЫ ЗАНЯТЫ" + "\n";
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Состояние СМО: " + CmoPosition.ToString() + "\n";
                    for (i = 0; i < NumOfChannels; i++)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.Text += "Состояние " + (i + 1).ToString() + "-го канала : " + Convert.ToString(ChannelBusy[i]) + "\n";
                        richTextBox1.Text += "Время окончания обслуживания в " + (i + 1).ToString() + " канале: " + Convert.ToString(ServiceTimeOfChannel[i]) + "\n";

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // информация о поступившей заявке
        private void Info(double CmoTime, ulong NumOfOrders)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Время поступления " + NumOfOrders.ToString() + "-й заявки: " + CmoTime.ToString() + "\n";
        }

        private void InfoOrder(double CmoTime, int Index, double TimeOfChannel)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Заявка принята на обслуживание: " + CmoTime.ToString() + " в " + (Index + 1).ToString() + "-й канал" + "\n";
            richTextBox1.Text += "Время обслуживания заявки в канале: " + TimeOfChannel.ToString() + "\n";
            richTextBox1.Text += "Время окончания обслуживания: " + ServiceTimeOfChannel[Index].ToString() + "\n";
        }
        // конструктор формы
        public WorkForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        // ПУСК
        private void btnStart_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Считывание данных
            if (TBoxOrders.Text != "" && TBoxOrderService.Text != "" && TBoxChannels.Text != "" && comboBoxPrecision.Text != "" && TBoxCmoWork.Text != "")
            {

                this.Enabled = false;

                InOrders = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxOrders.Text);
                ServiceOrders = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxOrderService.Text);
                NumOfChannels = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxChannels.Text);
                Precision = Convert.ToDouble(comboBoxPrecision.SelectedItem.ToString(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                richTextBox1.Text = "";
                int i = 0;
                // установление размерности массивов
                ChannelBusy = new int[NumOfChannels];
                ServiceTimeOfChannel = new double[NumOfChannels];

                TotalTime = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxCmoWork.Text);

                // Перевод системы в первоначальное состояние (обнуление всех переменных)
                CmoTime = 0;
                CmoPosition = 0;
                NumOfOrders = 0;
                ServedOrders = 0;

                while (i <= NumOfChannels - 1)
                {
                    ChannelBusy[i] = 0;
                    ServiceTimeOfChannel[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                }

                // Генерация поступления первой заявки
                CmoTime = TimeGenerator(true, OrderInterval, Precision);
                richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + "-----------------------" + "\n";
                richTextBox1.Text += "Текущее время СМО :" + CmoTime.ToString();
                richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + "-----------------------" + "\n";
                NumOfOrders++;
                Info(CmoTime, NumOfOrders);
                CmoCheck(TotalTime, CmoTime, NumOfChannels);
                CmoWork(CmoTime, NumOfChannels, ChannelInterval, Precision);
                // Последующая работа системы
                do
                {
                    // Генерация следующих моментов времени СМО
                    CmoTime = Math.Round((CmoTime + TimeGenerator(false, OrderInterval, Precision)), ChisloZnakov(Precision));

                    richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + "-----------------------" + "\n";
                    richTextBox1.Text += "Текущее время СМО :" + CmoTime.ToString();
                    richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + "-----------------------" + "\n";

                    // Проверка системы в текущий момент времени
                    CmoCheck(TotalTime, CmoTime, NumOfChannels);

                    // Появление новой заявки
                    if ((NewOrder(CmoTime, OrderInterval, NumOfOrders)) && (CmoTime <= TotalTime))
                    {
                        NumOfOrders++;
                        Info(CmoTime, NumOfOrders);
                        CmoWork(CmoTime, NumOfChannels, ChannelInterval, Precision);
                    }
                } while (CmoTime < TotalTime);
                richTextBox1.Text += "Количество поступивших заявок: " + NumOfOrders.ToString() + "\n";
                richTextBox1.Text += "Количество обслуженных заявок: " + ServedOrders.ToString() + "\n";

                this.Enabled = true;
                this.Focus();
                btnResult.Enabled = true;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Все поля обязательны для заполнения!");
        }

        // проверка вводимых значений
        private bool Check(string Txt)
        {
            try
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(Txt);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вводимое значение должно быть целым числом");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // ввод входящего потока
        private void TBoxOrders_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TBoxOrderService.Enabled = true;
        }

        // ввод интенсивности обслуживания
        private void TBoxOrderService_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TBoxChannels.Enabled = true;
        }
        // ввод количества каналов
        private void TBoxChannels_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TBoxCmoWork.Enabled = true;
        }

        // выбор точности
        private void comboBoxPrecision_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Precision = Convert.ToDouble(comboBoxPrecision.SelectedItem.ToString());
            TBoxOrders.Enabled = true;
        }
        // завершение ввода входящего потока
        private void TBoxOrders_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TBoxOrders.Text != "" && (btnExit.ContainsFocus == false))
            {
                if (Check(TBoxOrders.Text))
                {
                    InOrders = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxOrders.Text);
                    OrderInterval = OrdersInterval(InOrders, Precision);
                    labelOrdersInterval.Text = OrderInterval.ToString() + " ед.вр.";
                }
                else TBoxOrders.Focus();
            }
        }

        // завершение ввода интенсивности обслуживания
        private void TBoxOrderService_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TBoxOrderService.Text != "" && (btnExit.ContainsFocus == false))
            {
                if (Check(TBoxOrderService.Text))
                {
                    ServiceOrders = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxOrderService.Text);
                    ChannelInterval = OrdersInterval(ServiceOrders, Precision);
                    labelChannelInterval.Text = ChannelInterval.ToString() + " ед.вр.";
                }
                else TBoxOrderService.Focus();
            }
        }

        // завершение ввода количества каналов
        private void TBoxChannels_Leave_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TBoxChannels.Text != "" && (btnExit.ContainsFocus == false))
            {
                if (Check(TBoxChannels.Text))
                {
                    NumOfChannels = Convert.ToInt32(TBoxChannels.Text);
                }
                else TBoxChannels.Focus();
            }
        }
        // ОТЧЕТ
        private void btnResult_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResultForm FResult = new ResultForm(this, NumOfChannels, Precision, TotalTime, NumOfOrders, ServedOrders);
            FResult.Show();
        }

        private void WorkForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnResult.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void comboBoxPrecision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы не пробовали запустить программу в режиме отладки и смотреть, как она отрабатывает? Если программа виснет - значит, в ней есть какой-то бесконечный цикл, в котором она застревает навечно. Вот например у вас `while (CmoTime < TotalTime)` а есть уверенность, что когда-нибудь это условие нарушится?

Comment: @AK, отладка ругается на строчку    NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);

Comment: @AK, можете помочь с настройкой программы более подробно?

Comment: Я пока не проверял, но уверен, что проблема в методе TimeGenerator. Попробуйте отладить второй заказ и смотрите внимательно на GenerationInferval. Если GenerationInterval когда-либо равен 1 (а у вас это не исключено), цикл do while будет выполняться вечно

Comment: @Philippe Проверил, действительно происходит генерация 1 в GenerationInterval. Подскажите, как устранить это?

Comment: @Alex Вы намекаете на то, что я Вам предложил плохой код в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839202?

Comment: @Igor, нет, ошибка где-то в расчетах или при конвертации. Извиняюсь если как-то задел. Новичок и пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: @Alex это я пошутил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private int Precition(double e)
    {
        double EPSILON = 0.0001;
        int Tochnost = 0;

        if (Math.Abs(e - 0.1) < EPSILON)
            Tochnost = 10;
        else if (Math.Abs(e - 0.01) < EPSILON)
            Tochnost = 100;
        else if (Math.Abs(e - 0.001) < EPSILON)
            Tochnost = 1000;
        else
            throw new Exception("Not Found Precision: e = " + e.ToString());

        return Tochnost;
    }
```

Все другие места, где есть точное сравнение на равенство чисел с плавающей точкой (например, `ChisloZnakov`), тоже переписать.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, попробую переписать. Огромный респект за помощь

Comment: а почему ругается на `NotFoundException`?