# При конвертации в String - вывод "не число"

Tags: c#

Есть цикл, в котором генерируется NewTime. Решил проверить, какое число там получается, поставил MessageBox, и на выводе показывает что NewTime - "не число"

```
if (!FirstOrder)
            {
                // исключение генерации нуля => повторяющееся время
                do
                {
                    NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);
                    MessageBox.Show("New Time",Convert.ToString(NewTime));
                } while (NewTime == 0);
            }
            else
                NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);
```

Comment: `0/0` - "Not a Number"? Покажите отдельно числитель и знаменатель.

Comment: @Igor, ((случайное число > 0) % 1)  / 100

Comment: Выведите по отдельности все составляющие этого выражения.

Comment: @Igor, да, увидел, происходит деление 0/0. Надо где-то значит еще коде искать ошибку. Можете помочь с этим?

Comment: А зачем это? Пользуйте родные *time функции/классы, там же все есть в избытке.

Comment: Могу подсказать. Не используйте вызовы функций в выражениях. Это делает более сложной отладку, хотя и экономит строчки кода. Сохраняйте результаты вызовов в локальные переменные. Тогда в отладчике будет легче увидеть, откуда берутся проблемные значения.

Comment: @Igor, можете глянуть программу, если скину?

Comment: это тот код, который в другом вопросе?

Comment: @Igor, да это он

Comment: У меня сейчас рабочий день заканчивается, надо уходить. Могу дома посмотреть, но ничего не гарантирую. Как я уже сказал, надо отлаживать.

Comment: @Igor, конечно, буду благодарен если сможете, если не получится все равно спасибо за уделенное время, да и на вопросы мои отвечаете

Comment: `TimeSpan diff = dateTime1 - dateTime2; if (diff < 0) {...}` вот в эту сторону проще смотреть

Comment: @NewView, если можете, гляньте другой мой вопрос, там залил весь код. Думаю TimeSpan мне будет неуместно использовать, именно в моем случае. Может ошибаюсь. Буду рад если сможете подсказать как лучше

Comment: Ссылку на тото вопрос где код

Comment: @NewView https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839222