# Происходит генерация 0 в следствии цикла

Tags: c#

Есть переменная CmoTime, в которой происходит постоянно генерация 0, хотя вроде не должно `CmoTime = TimeGenerator(true, OrderInterval, Precision);`(К примеру с такими числами OrderInterval=0.06, Precision=0.01). А вот и сам TimeGenerator (Interval=0.01, Precition(Tochnost)=100)

```
private double TimeGenerator(bool FirstOrder,  double Tochnost, double Interval)
        {
            double NewTime;
            int GenerationInterval = (int)(Interval * Precition(Tochnost) + 1);

            // только если это не первая заявка
            if (!FirstOrder)
            {
                // исключение генерации нуля => повторяющееся время
                do
                {
                    NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);
                }  while (NewTime == 0);
            }
            else NewTime = (double)(rand.Next() % GenerationInterval) / Precition(Tochnost);
            return Math.Round(NewTime, ChisloZnakov(Tochnost));
        }
```

Comment: Вы переписали функцию `Precition`?

Comment: Да, как и говорили

Comment: :) Разве это тот код, который я написал?

Comment: @Igor, кстати, если убирать деление на Precition(Tochnost), то проходит нормально

Comment: @Igor, извиняюсь, забыл. Когда вставляю ваш код - то вывод идет "не число", а так вроде бы сработало. Может не прав, исправьте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция `Precition` возвращает ноль. Моя функция `Precition` из [Программа перестает работать после начала вычислений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839222) не может возвращать ноль. Но вы закомментировали в ней `throw`, поэтому она все равно возвращает ноль.

Так как `Precition` возвращает ноль, `GenerationInterval` равен единице.

Так как `GenerationInterval` равен единице, `rand.Next() % GenerationInterval` - будет ноль.

Следовательно,  `NewTime = 0/0;` - "не число".